# Show and Hide accordion content

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, laravel-8

[image]

I want to make a accordion like this.If I complete a lesson that will hide and will show next lesson. And I want to keep only one accordion open. How can I do that on Laravel, Bootstrap,JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this, you can be used as a reference

```css
  [aria-expanded="false"] > .expanded, [aria-expanded="true"] > .collapsed {
        display: none;
    }
    
    p {
      margin-left:14px;
      font-size:12px;
      color:#333;
      margin-bottom:-6px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
        
 
<div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#menuone" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="menuone">
                <span class="collapsed"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span> 
                <span class="expanded"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></span> 
                <strong>Section-1</strong>
                <p>
                  0/1 | 30 Min
                </p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="menuone" class="collapse">
          <div class="card-body">
              section description-1
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#menutwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="menutwo">
                <span class="collapsed"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span> 
                <span class="expanded"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></span> 
                <strong>Section-2</strong>
                <p>
                  0/2 | 45 Min
                </p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="menutwo" class="collapse">
          <div class="card-body">
                  section description-2
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse"  href="#menu3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="menu3">
                <span class="collapsed"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span> 
                <span class="expanded"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></span> 
                <strong>Section-3</strong>
                <p>
                  0/3 | 23 Min
                </p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="menu3" class="collapse">
          <div class="card-body">
                  section description-3
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/4oue8cL9/

Answer (score 0):

This code checks for every checkbox in the dropdown content, if all checkboxes are checked, it moves to the next dropdown, if it is the last dropdown, it just closes itself.

```js
      const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");
      dropdowns.forEach((e, i) => {
        const h = e.querySelector(".info");
        h.addEventListener("click", () => {
          dropdowns.forEach((ee, ii) => {
            const c = ee.querySelector(".content");
            if (ii != i) c.style.display = "none";
            else {
              if (c.style.display == "none" || c.style.display == "") c.style.display = "flex";
              else c.style.display = "none";
            }
          });
        });

        const c = e.querySelector(".content");
        const checks = c.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
        checks.forEach((e) => {
          e.addEventListener("change", () => {
            const cs = Array.from(c.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']")).map((e) => e.checked);
            if (cs.indexOf(false) == -1 && i < dropdowns.length - 1) {
              dropdowns.forEach((ee, ii) => {
                const c = ee.querySelector(".content");
                if (ii != i + 1) c.style.display = "none";
                else {
                  if (c.style.display == "none" || c.style.display == "") c.style.display = "flex";
                  else c.style.display = "none";
                }
              });
            } else if (cs.indexOf(false) == -1) {
              c.style.display = "none";
            }
          });
        });
      });
```

```css
      .dropdown {
        background-color: green;
      }

      .dropdown > .info {
        background-color: lightgray;
        border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .dropdown > .content {
        background-color: grey;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 10px;
        display: none;
      }

      h2,
      p {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
      <div class="info">
        <h2>header</h2>
        <p>information</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" /> Lesson 1</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" /> Lesson 2</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" /> Lesson 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="info">
        <h2>header</h2>
        <p>information</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia, optio in? Consequuntur voluptatibus
          repellat neque, aliquid maiores quisquam. Laborum ut minima id accusamus exercitationem, in obcaecati alias
          ducimus et ipsum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="info">
        <h2>header</h2>
        <p>information</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" /> Lesson 1</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" /> Lesson 2</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" /> Lesson 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="info">
        <h2>header</h2>
        <p>information</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" /> Lesson 1</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" /> Lesson 2</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" /> Lesson 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="info">
        <h2>header</h2>
        <p>information</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" /> Lesson 1</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" /> Lesson 2</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" /> Lesson 3</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: @HasibShanto no problem, but if you don't have any more questions, please just mark this question as answered, so people don't waste time answering an already answered question :)

Comment: pardon actually I'm new here can you tell me how to mark

Comment: @HasibShanto just click on the check mark on the answer you think is the right one, its beneath the upvote button